In Azure devops release pipeline, is there a better option than Windows Machine File Copy task to copy file to an AWS EC2 with Windows 19?
I have a release pipeline in azure devops that needs to copy a single artifact file from the results of a build pipeline to an AWS EC2 thats running Windows 2019.  Currently, the release pipeline uses a Deployment Group job and then the Windows Machine File Copy task.  The issue is, the deployment group job downloads the entire project artifacts on the the target EC2 first.  Then the Windows Machine File Copy task takes a single file and moves it to a directory.
Is using an Agent job a better option then the Deployment Group job, and is that possible in this instance?  Should i also be looking at other tasks besides the Windows Machine File Copy?
I would like to avoid downloading the entire set of artifacts on the target server if possible. If i could only download a specific file and then copy it to the target directory that would be preferred.


Is using an Agent job a better option then the Deployment Group job, and is that possible in this instance?

In your case, Agent job and Deployment Group Job can achieve the same function.
They can all use the copy file task to copy the files to the corresponding path on the server.
When you use Agent job, you need to setup a self-hosted agent on AWS EC2 Windows 2019 server.
You can choose one of method according to your preference.

Should i also be looking at other tasks besides the Windows Machine File Copy?

If the target directory is on a different Windows server machine, you can keep using Windows Machine File Copy task.
If the target directory is on the same windows server where the Agent is located, you can also change to use the Copy file task to achieve the same feature.  This task doesn't need to input the windows username and password.

I would like to avoid downloading the entire set of artifacts on the target server if possible. If i could only download a specific file and then copy it to the target directory

By default, the whole build artifact will be downloaded for deployment, we can't control this behavior in release pipeline built-in feature.
For a workaround, we can skip the default download artifacts step of the release pipeline. And then we can add the Download Build Artifacts task or Download Pipeline artifacts task to set the required files to download instead of the entire artifacts.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Navigate to Deployment Group job/Agent Job -> Additional options and enable the option: Skip download of artifacts.
For example:

In some organizations, you may see the option Artifact download instead. In this case, you can unselect all artifacts.
For example:

step2: You can add download build artifacts task or download pipeline artifacts task in your deployment job. Then you can set the files to download in Matching patterns field.
For example:

